# How to increase Page Width with the Help of CSS?

Tags: html, css

Please Have a look i am showing a List of record in a page and each list item have a menu also

**Image1**

It is showing fine in page 
[image: Displaying all menu item]

**Image2**

[image: Not displaying all items]

Here you can check all menu item is not displaying because this is the last item of List. Can someone suggest how to increase page height in second case

**EDIT:**

After adding below css code

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;

}
```

Page look like this

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

CSS Used

```
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
    right: 0px;
    left: auto;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Comment: Either add some whitespace at the bottom of the page to cater for the menu, or add some functionality to the menu so if it ever hits the bottom of the page actually goes up the page, rather than down. (if that makes sense).

Comment: I tried to add height of Listbox and Page and other component but not fixed

Comment: @ Michael Bellamy your solution make sense

Comment: Any Idea how to right this type of CSS which will open Menu upward or downwards

Comment: What is `position` css dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
If dropdown menu `position` is `absolute` change it to `relative`. Also if there `Right` css code change it to `float:right`.

```
.menu-css{
position: relative;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: I tried that position: relative ; but it is making weird change it change menu button position right

Comment: Its increasing listcell height as well and now listcell have same height like Menu

Comment: @subodh If you can give a demo. I can help you better and faster.

Comment: See i have edited question and added what the issue i am facing?

Comment: @subodh Please give me complete css code dropdown menu without changing.

Comment: Added CSS in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75184/discussion-between-rockstar-and-subodh).

Answer (score 0):

Best way to solve this is, to open the menu upward from that position when you are in the bottom of the page.

Comment: ANy idea how to write that css ?